# "This file came from another computer and might be blocked to help protect this computer" - how do I stop having to unblock files in MS Word?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word, security, microsoft-word-2010

When I download Word Documents from Outlook that have come from a source external to my organization, I am unable to open them.

When I check the properties of the document, I see that the file needs to be 'unblocked'.

[image: This file came from another computer...]

When I 'unblock' to file, I am able to open it in Word. How can I stop Word Documents from third parties via email needing to be 'unblocked' in this way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Click **File > Options**.
2. On the Window that opens, Click **Trust Center > Trust Center Settings > Protected View**
   [image]
3. Deselect the third option **"Enable Protected view for outlook attachments"**

Note: as said by [@Ramhound](https://superuser.com/questions/1691737/this-file-came-from-another-computer-and-might-be-blocked-to-help-protect-this/1691740#comment2601206_1691740), you might not be able to change the settings yourself. In this case try contacting your administrator.

Comment: Depending on the organization the author might not be able to change this setting themselves, this setting can indeed be set or disabled through a group policy, so contacting an Administrator to disable it would be the correct step if they are unable to disable it themselves.